# How do I persist sales price in an orders details table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a simple transactional database to practice my T-SQL skills.
If I sell an umbrella in my sales.orderdetails table and it's getting the current retailprice of that umbrella from the items table and putting it in the invoice, how do I keep from having incorrect historical report data 6 months from now when I jack up the retail price of the umbrella by $10?

How do i store that umbrella sold price in the orderdetails table so it's unaffected by any changes in the items table in the future?
I know you can use an SCD for a datawarehouse for this kind of issue but was wondering how to do it in an OLTP system.  Computed persisted column?  Can't seem to get that to work in the object explorer when I try to enter the items.retailprice as the computed value for the salesorderdetails.cost column.

Answer (score 3):

The way I have seen this done in the past, without using a technique like SCD, was to have the order detail have the price that was charged and then use a foreign key to another table, possibly products or productprices, that contains the current price.

Answer (score 1):

In a full-on transactional system, you'd want the order detail row to record full retail (MSRP, or what have you), current price (in case you had the item posted at a discount that day), and price charged (in case the customer used a promo/coupon code to reduce the price themselves). Unless you log all three, you're at the mercy of whatever the price changes to tomorrow or next week or next year, which makes for bad analytics.

You probably also want to capture current cost of goods, too, since that's subject to change over time, especially in an average costing scenario. Otherwise, margin calculations will be suspect.

But then, yes, a foreign key or keys to any other descriptive tables for those less ephemeral characteristics of the product.